# What is "minlex order" when representing a sudoku puzzle?

Tags: sudoku

For a sudoku puzzle:

```
000000010400000000020000000000050407008000300001090000300400200050100000000806000
```

in it's *minlex order* form:

```
000000001000000020000003000000040500006000300007810000010020004030000070950000000
```

What is the meaning of *minlex order* and how the above puzzle is drawn in a 9x9 layout?

Source: [Minimum Sudoku](http://school.maths.uwa.edu.au/~gordon/sudokumin.php) 1st puzzle.

UPDATE:

Diagram 1:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 5 0 4 0 7
0 0 8 0 0 0 3 0 0
0 0 1 0 9 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 4 0 0 2 0 0
0 5 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 8 0 6 0 0 0
```

Diagram 2:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0
0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 4 0 5 0 0
0 0 6 0 0 0 3 0 0
0 0 7 8 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 4
0 3 0 0 0 0 0 7 0
9 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Sounds like minimum lexicographic. Then 000000001000000020000003000000040500006000300007810000010020004030000070950000000 is the lowest representation of the same puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The puzzle is drawn from the specification by writing each number in a grid space, starting from the top left, going across the top row, and then starting on the second row from left to right until all nine rows are filled in. A zero corresponds to a blank space.

Like this:

```
      1    2    3     4    5    6     7    8    9
   +---------------+---------------+---------------+
A  |  .    .    .  |  .    .    .  |  .    1    .  |
B  |  4    .    .  |  .    .    .  |  .    .    .  |
C  |  .    2    .  |  .    .    .  |  .    .    .  |
   |---------------+---------------+---------------|
D  |  .    .    .  |  .    5    .  |  4    .    7  |
E  |  .    .    8  |  .    .    .  |  3    .    .  |
F  |  .    .    1  |  .    9    .  |  .    .    .  |
   |---------------+---------------+---------------|
G  |  3    .    .  |  4    .    .  |  2    .    .  |
H  |  .    5    .  |  1    .    .  |  .    .    .  |
I  |  .    .    .  |  8    .    6  |  .    .    .  |
   +---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

The *minlex* form of a Sudoku puzzle is the equivalent puzzle that sorts first in alphabetical order (from left to right). Puzzles are considered equivalent if one can be converted to the other by interchanging row and columns and renumbering without changing the puzzle.

Comment: The first puzzle linked from the site is drawn as [this digram](http://school.maths.uwa.edu.au/~gordon/sudoku.php?a=000000010400000000020000000000050407008000300001090000300400200050100000000806000), which I cannot see any relevance with the _minlex_ version.

Comment: They are *structurally* the same. If you solve one, for each step, there will be a perfectly corresponding step in the other. You can convert one into the other just by swapping rows (like A for C, or GHI for ABC), swapping columns  (like 4 for 6 or 789 for 123), or swapping numbers (like changing every '2' to a '9').

Comment: Please see my UPDATE, does it mean Diagram 1 is equal to Diagram 2? Did I draw Diagram 2 correctly from the _minlex order_ form?

Comment: @ohho Your diagram's right. They are equivalent. For example, in the original puzzle, the first step is realizing that, by process of elimination, G5 must be 7. In the minlex version, identical reasoning shows G3 must be 8. Next, in the original, D6 is the only cell in its column that can be a 1 and D8 is the only cell in its column that can be an 8. Identical reasoning in the minlex version shows that F1 is the only cell in its column that can be a 3 and F6 is the only cell in its column that can be a 5. Next, H5/I5 must be 2/3 in the original, H3/I3 must be 2/4 in the minlex. And so on.